# Cron log shows error 302

Tags: php, cron

I am having an issue in receiving email through cron that runs daily. When i run the file manually in browser than i am able to see the output in browser and also receives email. But through cron the email is not sent. It is redirected to error page and in cron logs says 302 Found and also  Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at example.net Port 443.

Comment: `302` is not error code, it's redirect code. Show code please.

Comment: The file was named "HappyBirthday.php". Everytime the same code on other file was running perfectly but not with this file name. I changed the name of file and now it is working fine. Don't know what is the problem with this name. But somehow it get resolved.

Comment: Was there inconsistency with UPPER and lower case letters between file name and calling string? *NIX is case sensitive.